# Need a expression to find comma separated string in a List<string>

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, predicate

i am creating a generic method which generates predicate to filter data. this is my contains method

```
Expression.Call(Member, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), constant)
```

like wise i need a expression to find comma separated string in a list of string. please help.

```
List<string> abc;
string xyz = "a,d,j";
```

then if list of string having xyz string i.e. a or d or j string it will filter list of string accordingly.

Comment: Why not `String.Split` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i need the expression so that it can generate predicate, i have to use it in my generic method. can you please help me make expression !

Comment: Please clarify and provide more sample data. How exactly should the `filter list of string` work? What are the contents of `List<string> abc`? Please be specific.

Comment: @Ryan List<string> lst ={abc,qwe,zxc } and i have to find b,z so it should return {abc,zxc}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, using the values from your comment:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = new List<string>() { "abc", "qwe", "zxc" };
    string filter = "b,z";
    var results = input.Where(i => ContainsAny(i, filter));
}

bool ContainsAny(string input, string filter)
{
    var filters = filter.Split(',');
    foreach (var f in filters)
        if (input.Contains(f))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you provide this in terms of expression  so that i can use like others as predecate in where condition

Comment: @summ the `ContainsAny` is the predicate. You can move the `Split` into the ContainsAny method though. I'll update it.